# Can't run ANY xbuntu, stuck at boot

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

When booting Ubuntu/Lubuntu and others it's stuck at one point shown in the screenshots linked to below.

I tried installing from Windows, but when choosing Ubuntu after start it shows some text trying different filesystems and short error, but it disappears fast so I can't read it.

**Hardware**

- Motherboard: Gigabyte ga-870a UD3 BIOS: the newest FEf
- CPU: AMD FX-6200 Six-Core
- 8GB RAM
- 1st SSD: Plextor 128GB (Windows 7)
- 2nd SSD: Intel 830 (trying to put Linux here, currently here is GRUB, 1st boot HDD)
- 2x HDD

Comment: It could be your BIOS settings. Gigabyte motherboards are tricky about booting from SSDs. Search for posts related to your motherboard in the Gigabyte product forum, especially for problems related to booting from an SSD. If that doesn't help, try searching in the Gigabyte product forum for similar problems with similar motherboards.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

Set AMD C1E support to DISABLED in BIOS.